# Mime type for a flash as3 (.as) file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, wordpress, mime-types

Ive been googling for a few hours now and cant find this little snippet of information...

I need to add the mimetype for a .as file to allow a wordpress site to upload a flash .as file (actionscript 3)

Anyone know what the mime type is for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`application/x-actionscript` and `text/x-actionscript` seem to be mentioned the most. The text version would probably be most applicable to a source file.

Answer (score 0):

Just so people know:

I tried both of the above `application/x-actionscript` and `text/x-actionscript`

Only the `application/x-actionscript` worked.